# Google Drive API - Adding and Updating Permissions

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, google-drive-api

I'm working on file sharing on Google Drive in my android app. Here is the scenario... User A shares a file with User B, gives him/her the "writer" role. Later, forgetful User A, again, shares the same file with User B, giving him/her the "reader" role this time. My question is, will this override the first permission? or should the app handle checking of existing file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drive.permissions.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update) to update `role` property of a `permission`, provided that you have `fileId` and `permissionId`. The `role` property will be overridden. But if you notice, there is a `additionalRoles[]` property that will allow you to add secondary roles to that permission given to a user. Right now, only `commenter` is allowed. Maybe in the future, more roles will be added in that property.

You can confirm by yourself using [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/):

1. First, send `drive.files.list` request to get `fileId` of a shared
   file.
2. Send `drive.permissions.list` request with the `fileId` to get
   `permissionId` of a user (it is the `id` in the reponse).
3. With `fileId` and `permissionId`, now you can use
   `drive.permissions.update` to change the role of that user by send
   the request with `role` property in the body.

Comment: Thank you! So in order to get the `permissionId`, I'll have to loop through the permissions list and get the permission with the value property equal to a user's email, right?

Comment: If you want to get permission given to the authenticated user only (who use your app), send `drive.files.list` request is enough. The response will contain `userPermission` field which provides `id`,`role`,`type` of that user toward a file. Notice that you can use permission `id` as `me` instead of the full id string for the authenticated user. Otherwise if you want to get permissions that give to all users, then yes, you need to send `drive.permission.list` request to get the list of users and update their `role`s

Comment: I'm not sure if user who has `owner` role can be change to another role. I tried with API explorer and it gives me `500 Internal Server Error`